# How to redirect to a custom VFP after a Custom Object record is created (Standard way of insert)?

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, custom-object, urlhacking

well, pretty much as the title says.

I need the user to be redirected to a Custom VFP when a new record of a Custom Object is created, additional to this I need to be able to send the Id to that Custom VFP (I think I have the solution for this but want to confirm it).

**What I have done so far**

Tried using the override to the View button, but this led me to the Custom VFP without the Id and also whenever I want to view a different record, it takes me to the Custom VFP which I don't want to.

Tried to call a PageReference method in a trigger after inserted record, I think this way could be possible if I find the proper way to hack it.

My boss told that this was possible via trigger...

Please help :( and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your boss is incorrect; it's not possible via a trigger. Triggers have no context of a user interface, because they may be called from the API, Apex Code, etc. The only solution is to override the New Record page with a Visualforce Page, perform the save from the controller, and then redirect.

Comment: I thought about that, but as I'm still new in this, didn't want to go so deep, but guess what, I followed what you say and it works (almost perfect , just gotta do some adjustments).